# How to find Ratio And proportion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $\frac{4x+3y}{4x-3y}=\frac{7}{5}$.Find the Value of the $\frac{2x^2-11y^2}{2x^2+11y^2}$.
Okay I just want hint how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Just notice that
$$\frac{4x+3y}{4x-3y}=\frac{7}{5}\qquad\implies\qquad 5(4x+3y)=7(4x-3y)\qquad\implies\qquad 36y=8x$$
So $y=\frac{2}{9}x$, then
$$\frac{2x^2-11y^2}{2x^2+11y^2}=\frac{2x^2-\frac{44}{81}x^2}{2x^2+\frac{44}{81}x^2}=\frac{2\cdot 81-44}{2\cdot 81+44}$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

The pattern reminds me of [Componendo and Dividendo](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/)

$$\dfrac{4x}{3y}=\dfrac{7+5}{7-5}=6\iff\dfrac xy=?$$

$$\implies\dfrac{2x^2}{11y^2}=?$$

Now apply Componendo and Dividendo

Answer (score 1):

In your first equation $\frac{4x+3y}{4x-3y}=\frac{7}{5}$, try solving x in terms of y or vice versa.

Then you will find that $x=\frac{9}{2}y$ or $y=\frac{2}{9}x$,

so now substitute one of these to $\frac{2x^2-11y^2}{2x^2+11y^2}$

if you choose $x=\frac{9}{2}y$ you'll have,

$$\frac{2x^2-11y^2}{2x^2+11y^2}=\frac{\frac{81}{2}y^2-11y^2}{\frac{81}{2}y^2+11y^2}$$

cancelled all y^2, finally you have $\frac{81-22}{81+22}=\frac{59}{103}$

also if you choose $y=\frac{2}{9}x$, same process and you'll have $\frac{59}{103}$ as an answer.